# Interacting with attendance biometric device using OCX dll

Tags: c#, exception, dll, biometrics

I am using visual studio 2012. I am trying to interact with a biometric attendance device through a desktop application via ip address. I added the necessary dll and ocx files to the reference folder of the project. I created the object of `'SB100PCLib'` quite easily, but when  I try to execute its functions, I get this run time error

> *Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))*

As I am quite new dealing with third party dll, is there any extra step to perform? 
How to get rid of the error?

Comment: @Ikran did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to have close look at this post : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739194/en-us
thanx

Comment: Its totally out of the scope :/